# DC pass cable splitter

Tags: coaxial-cable

So we have a direct tv satellite that we don’t use anymore. They left a dc pass cable splitter hooked up. Can we use that to hook up an outdoor antenna? Will we get shocked or something? Clearly we don’t know what we’re doing. I wasn’t sure if I should just get a regular splitter or could use the one that’s already hooked up to our cables.

Comment: Called a buddy that used to work for DirecTV, his opinion but he didn't have much time to talk, was you should probably just switch it out (good quality splitters are under 10 bucks).  He's afraid you actually have an amplified splitter, which won't work for anything other than DirecTV.  Another hint: identify the cables you need to hook up and buy a splitter with just that number of ports.  With TV signal you lose 7.5db per port so you don't want extra ports or unused cables connected.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could use it, but unless you need the splitter function, you do not want any extra splitters in your antenna line, as each one cuts your antenna signal (tiny) by half. Use a straight barrel connector if you need to join two cable ends.

The "DC pass" part of the one you have was to permit power to be passed up to an amplifier built into the dish receiver for the satellite. If does not make you any more or less likely to "get shocked or something." If you are installing an antenna, you should learn about [not causing the antenna cable to look like the best place for lightning to run into the house.](http://dennysantennaservice.com/1171010.html) (not affilated with the linked content, nor is it directly relevant to this question, so I'm not going to copy it here, either. Might make a good question for someone to ask.)